# How do you integrate a wordpress blog into an existing website

Tags: php, wordpress, integration

So I have a client that has a website customized in PHP that does not use an actual Content Management System. The website presently has a Blog and News section, also coded in PHP without a CMS.

My client now wants to have only the Blog and News Sections created with Wordpress, but seamlessly go with the existing site. The benefits in their mind is that they only need to hire bloggers and give them access to the Wordpress aspect of the site, while leaving the other parts of the site administered by his staff.

I think that this will require obviously a Wordpress installation, and perhaps some shared database resources.

If anyone has ever done or seen this, please let me know.

Comment: In the easiest scenario Wordpress can live in a separate  web-accessible folder on the site. Say '/blog'.  It sounds like they just want clear separation, so this approach may be possible.  It's a bit more difficult if design elements (common headers/footers, etc) need to be shared between the two systems.

Comment: What if they want a /news too? Can I use the same WP installation to pull this off?

Comment: Sure, you might use some symlinks to pull it off in the directory structure.  There are a lot of ways. If you want to get tricky you can setup an RSS feed on Wordpress and have portions of the existing site consume it for fuller integration.  There are probably plugins that allow you to build widgets in a similar fashion.  It's all possible, just may be more effort than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out from wordpress codex itself -
http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website

The easiest way to have both news & blog would be to " create 2 different categories within the blog" and display them differently using "The Loop"

http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Style_Posts_From_Some_Category_Differently

Comment: Could you please add a small description to accompany the links you provide?